# Explicit inverse of $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\alpha} (x+1)^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}} | x - 1 |^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \frac{\alpha(x - 1) + 2}{(x- 1)(x + 1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, special-functions, closed-form, inverse-function

In the very same spirit as my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4821282/545914) I am trying to find an explicit representation of the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) $f^*$ of the function
$$
f \colon \mathbb R \to [0, \infty], \qquad x \mapsto | 1 - x |^{\frac{1}{a}} (1 + x)^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}} + \iota_{[0, \infty)}(x),
$$
where for any set $A$, the convex indicator function $\iota_{A}(x)$ is equal to $0$ for $x \in A$ and equal to $\infty$ else and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.

> Up to edge cases, this first boils down to finding the inverse of
> $$
> f'(x)
> = \frac{1}{\alpha} (x+1)^{\frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}} | x - 1 |^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \frac{\alpha(x - 1) + 2}{(x- 1)(x + 1)}
> = \frac{1}{\alpha} \left| \frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \left(\alpha + \frac{2}{(x- 1)}\right)
> $$
> (to obtain $f^*(y) = y (f')^{-1}(y) - f((f')^{-1}(y))$.)

Due to the last term in parenthesis, I do not know how to invert $f'$, like it was done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4825654/545914). We have that $f'$ is strictly monotonically increasing and continuous, so that it is bijective onto its range and hence invertible.

For $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$, WolframAlpha gives an explicit inverse, which as a quite [complicated expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse%20of%20%28%282%20%2B%20x%29%20abs%28-1%20%2B%20x%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29%2F%28%28-1%20%2B%20x%29%20%281%20%2B%20x%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29), whereas for $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, it can't find an answer in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\a{\alpha}\DeclareMathOperator\I{I}$

Substitute $x=\frac{w+1}{w-1}$ (i.e. $w = \frac{x + 1}{x - 1}$):

$$\frac1\a\left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|^\frac1\a\left(\a+\frac2{x-1}\right)=y\iff |w|^\frac1a-\frac w{\a y}-\frac{\a-1}{\a y}=0$$

For $y < 0$ there is a closed Wolfram language form via [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636461/list-of-closed-form-special-cases-and-transformations-of-wolfram-language-s-inve) in section 1

> $$x^r+ax+b=0\implies x=\frac{b r}{a(1-r)\text I^{-1}_\frac{b^{r-1}(r-1)}{a^r\left(\frac1r-1\right)^r}(r-1,2)}$$

where [inverse beta regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) appears. Therefore:

$$\boxed{f(x)=|1-x|^\frac1\a(1+x)^\frac{\a-1}\a\implies (f’)^{-1}(x)=\frac2{\I^{-1}_{1-x}\left(2,\frac1\alpha-1\right)}-1,0\le x\le1}$$

testable [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B1%2Fa%7C%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%7C%5E%281%2Fa%29%28a%2B2%2F%28x-1%29%29-b%5D%2Cx%3D2%2FInverseBetaRegularized%281+-b%2C+2%2C+1%2Fa-1%29-1%2Ca%3D1%2F4%2Cb%3D0.4). Wolfram Alpha automatically reduces the solution to a radical form if possible.

Using $(f’)^{-1}(y)=\frac2u-1$, then $f^*(y)=2\frac{y-|1-u|^\frac1a}u-y$ using algebra and software. $1-u$ from section 7 can be used again and the absolute value removed as $u\ge0$ to get $$\boxed{f^*(y)=2\frac{y-\I^{-1}_y\left(\frac1\a-1,2\right)^\frac1\a}{\I^{-1}_{1-y}\left(2,\frac1\a-1\right)}-y,0\le y\le 1}$$

There is probably also a [series solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/), with closed forms for possibly the entire domain of $f(x)$ which will be added later.

Comment: The result is for the branch of the inverse in all of quadrant $1$. However, the absolute value makes it hard to come up with an $I^{-1}_x(a,b)$ solution for the other branch

Comment: @ViktorStein There should have been a more detailed derivation, but you can use $I^{-1}_x(a,b)=1-I^{-1}_{1-x}(b,a)$ (section 7 of the linked post) and find $x=\frac{w+1}{w-1}=\frac{\frac1{1-I}+1}{\frac1{1-I}-1}=\frac2I-1,I=I^{-1}_z(1-\frac1\alpha,2)$

Comment: Does one need $a > 0$ for the formula from section 1?

Comment: @ViktorStein Yes one does. For the formula in this answer, $r-1> 0$, so $r>1$

Comment: Because in section 1 it says "All three formulas account for any real $r$".

Comment: @ViktorStein There are a few formulas for $-r>0,r-1>0,\frac1r-1>0$, while $r=0,1$ is trivial and likely a limit can be used for these cases. Thus, $r\in\Bbb R$ is covered.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you.